# Flutter camera package, how can I rotate the image?

Tags: flutter

My code is simle;

```
 final XFile image=await cameraController!.takePicture();
 takenImage=await image.readAsBytes();
```

and when I am just using this two line, I can see the image with `Image.memory(_vm.takenImage!, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth)`

But i need to change picture rotation,

for this reason, I am using image package https://pub.dev/packages/image

so, why I am getting invalid image data after just these lines;

```
final XFile image=await cameraController!.takePicture();
takenImage=await image.readAsBytes();
img.Image? decodedImage=img.decodeImage(takenImage!);
takenImage=decodedImage!.getBytes();
```

If I delete the last two sentence it's working correctlye but if I add the last lines I am getting Exceltion: invalid image data, but why ? I mean .getBytes returning Uint8List, takenImage type is Uint8List? ...

if I can convert like my second code review, I can use the; img.copyRotate(originalImage!, 90).getBytes(); function, so please help me for understand.

Comment: If you solved it, add your solution as an answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @Suporte01 thank u sir, i will do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my problem related image type cause as you can see on question I wasn't encode my image with any type, so the solution and working code now can seen on below;

```
final XFile image=await cameraController!.takePicture();
img.Image? _capturedImage=img.decodeImage(await image.readAsBytes());
_capturedImage=img.copyRotate(_capturedImage!, 90);
takenImage=Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(_capturedImage));
```